# Performing a JOIN SQL method for this mentioned code

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables

company and company_meta

company table has following

```
------------------------
id | title | city
------------------------
1 | abc | nice city
2 | def | awesome city
------------------------
```

company_meta has

```
------------------------------------------------
id | company_id | meta_key | meta_value
------------------------------------------------
1 | 1 | feature_parking | Yes
2 | 1 | feature_fireexit | Yes
3 | 2 | feature_parking | No
4 | 2 | feature_gym | Yes
------------------------------------------------
```

Now i want to join these two tables in Laravel and PRINT it in such a way that it shows the following

```
Company 1 : nice city
Parking : Yes
Fire Exit : Yes
Gym : No (if not mentioned it must automatically consider as NO)

Company 2 : awesome city
Parking : No
Fire Exit : No
Gym : Yes
```

using Foreach statement.

I got the idea of this type of table relationship using meta by **seeing Wordpress DB.** Can also someone tell me **what is this type of relationship method called** so that I will google more tuts regarding the same.

Also is there any other better way of Creating DB relationships? My DB will have around **100,000 company data, with each company having 10-12 features each**. So it will be a very big Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `subquery` also below mentioned query also takes care of your this concerned **if not mentioned it must automatically consider as NO**

```
SELECT  
q.company_id,q.company_name,
CASE WHEN q.parking IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.parking END AS parking,
CASE WHEN q.fireexit IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.fireexit END AS fireexit,
CASE WHEN q.gym IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.gym END AS gym
 FROM (
SELECT cm.`company_id`,
(SELECT `title` FROM `company` WHERE id=cm.`company_id`) AS company_name,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_parking') AS parking,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_fireexit') AS fireexit,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_gym') AS gym 
 FROM `company_meta` cm GROUP BY cm.`company_id` ) q
```

Now in wordpress define the global variable `$wpdb` for the database interaction

```
global $wpdb;

$results= $wpdb->get_results("    SELECT  
    q.company_id,q.company_name,
    CASE WHEN q.parking IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.parking END AS parking,
    CASE WHEN q.fireexit IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.fireexit END AS fireexit,
    CASE WHEN q.gym IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE q.gym END AS gym
     FROM (
    SELECT cm.`company_id`,
    (SELECT `title` FROM `company` WHERE id=cm.`company_id`) AS company_name,
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_parking') AS parking,
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_fireexit') AS fireexit,
    (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `company_meta` WHERE company_id=cm.`company_id` AND meta_key ='feature_gym') AS gym 
     FROM `company_meta` cm GROUP BY cm.`company_id` ) q");

foreach($results as $r){

echo "Company ".$r->company_id ." : ".$r->company_name;
echo "Parking : ".$r->parking;
echo "Fire Exit : ".$r->fireexit;
echo "Gym : ".$r->gym;
}
```

[**HERE IS YOUR FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb27b/1)

I hope it works perfect for you

Comment: Actually I am not working with wordpress. I am working on laravel PHP but using similar database relationship structure as that of WP.

Comment: i have provided the query for your scenario

Comment: The SQL fiddle will help alot for me. Thanks

Comment: I can select only 1 correct answer, but his code and solution is correct. Your sql is correct. I am sorry i cant select yours. I am upvoting yours. Both answers are useful

Answer (score 1):

It is a **one to many** relationship. It doesn't seem to be anything bad with it the way you describe it. This kind of design is OK if you don't know beforehand how many meta-attributes each company might have.

You may want to add a **index** on the *company_id* column on the second table so you can merge both tables efficiently. Don't worry about your expected database size, it's not a huge number of records (databases are designed to handle millions of records). You might want to add another index as well on *meta_key* **if** you are planing to filter data based on having or not any particular set of features (i.e. Give me all companies with feature A and B but not C)

Comment: exactly, I want to filter too. I will look on about INDEX now. And one more thing. I will have a form field stating Parking with radio buttons YES / NO. When submit button is clicked, it should pass "feature_parking" to the meta_key and YES to the meta_value. How to pass both values together?

Comment: Set the id attribute on your html tag **id="meta_something"** and the value to *true* or *false*, then in your PHP (?) save it properly on your DB.

Comment: How setting a id tag will pass "feature_parking" to the meta_key in DB?? True or False is fine with the checkbox. It is usual Post method. But I am asking about the meta_key where it should get "feature_parking" default if parking field is entered based on which I will run the php to extract the data I need from the SQL.

Comment: I see, then add a hidden field (it's a different tag) with the value set to the meta_key you want. Then using php read the value of it. Another option is to sumbit the values "META_SOMETHING_TRUE" or "META_SOMETHING_FALSE" and then just do properly on your PHP

Comment: thanks, I will try that. But I am still trying to check if the above relationship is possible by Laravel

Comment: I´ve never used it but it should, it's probably the most used relationship.

Comment: It allows one-one, one-many, many-many etc etc. But what makes me think is, will it allow me to display data in pages based on the meta_key value in DB like how php basically does

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33043/discussion-between-xocoatzin-and-harishannam)